# getting first element of array in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am populating an array of objects in knockoutjs

I wanted to avoid the use of foreach, so I tried to `data-bind` the first item

if i use the below code it is working fine

```
<div class="loader" data-bind="foreach: Items" >
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
```

But if i use, the one below, its not working

```
<div class="loader">
        <span data-bind="text: Items[0].name"></span>
    </div>
```

What is the mistake in the second way?

The error I am getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function
>   (){return Items[0].name }" Message: Cannot read property 'name' of
>   undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well you need to `unwrap` the observableArray `Items` to read it's content using `()` notation .

Try like this

```
<div class="loader">
     <span data-bind="text: Items()[0].name"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: when I use the first one, it works everytime
but in this Items()[0], sometimes it causes the below error

`Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return Items()[0].Name}"
Message: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`

Comment: are you sure @vignesh `items` is always a observableArray or you directly binding json to view ? and in addition is `Name`  defined under the array .

Comment: Yeah. It is observableArray and .Name is defined in it
It works when I use the first way using ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

```
text: Items()[0].name
```

Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Use either `Items()[0].name` or `ko.unwrap(Items)[0]`
I would recommend the second one since it is safer because it would return the array even if Items is not an observable array, hence helps avoiding exceptions.

Comment: like this??
 `<span data-bind="text: ko.unwrap(Items)[0].name">`

Comment: yup @vignesh ! if at all `items` is non observable i.e plain java-script array .